# c# streaming over http to iphone not playing

Tags: c#, ios, iphone

I am trying to deliver mp4 object to iPhone device and i have tried the option posted on stackoverflow but didn't work in all the time. Only one time i am able to stream the video but in all other cases it fails. Can you please susggest how to resolve this.

Article I have tried below..
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Range-Specific-Requests-in-ASP-NET.aspx#rangespecific-requests-and-videos-on-the-iphone-and-ipod-touch

Below code execute for iPhone device

```
        if (Request.Headers[HTTP_HEADER_RANGE] != null)
        {
            rangeHeader = Request.Headers[HTTP_HEADER_RANGE];
            string[] ranges = rangeHeader.Replace("bytes=", string.Empty).Split(",".ToCharArray());
            StartRangeBytes = new long[ranges.Length];
            EndRangeBytes = new long[ranges.Length];

            EnableRangeRequests = true;
            IsMultipartRequest = (StartRangeBytes.Length > 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < ranges.Length; i++)
            {
                const int START = 0, END = 1;

                string[] currentRange = ranges[i].Split("-".ToCharArray());

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRange[END]))
                    EndRangeBytes[i] = InternalRequestedFileInfo.Length - 1;
                else
                    EndRangeBytes[i] = long.Parse(currentRange[END]);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRange[START]))
                {
                    StartRangeBytes[i] = InternalRequestedFileInfo.Length - 1 - EndRangeBytes[i];
                    EndRangeBytes[i] = InternalRequestedFileInfo.Length - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    StartRangeBytes[i] = long.Parse(currentRange[0]);
                }
            }
            ReturnPartialEntity();
        }

    private void ReturnPartialEntity()
    {
        sLog.Append("ReturnPartialEntity \r\n");
        Response.StatusCode = 206;  // Partial response
        AddHeader(Response, HTTP_HEADER_CONTENT_RANGE,
                                    string.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}",
                                                    StartRangeBytes[0].ToString(),
                                                    EndRangeBytes[0].ToString(),
                                                    InternalRequestedFileInfo.Length.ToString()
                                                  )
                                );

        WriteCommonResponseHeaders(Response,
                       ComputeContentLength(),
                       this.IsMultipartRequest ? MULTIPART_CONTENTTYPE : this.InternalRequestedFileMimeType);

        ReturnChunkedResponse();
    }

    private void WriteCommonResponseHeaders(HttpResponse Response, long contentLength, string contentType)
    {
        AddHeader(Response, HTTP_HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, contentLength.ToString());
        AddHeader(Response, HTTP_HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, contentType);
        if (!bIsiPhone)
            AddHeader(Response, "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + m_strTitle.Replace(" ", "_") + InternalRequestedFileInfo.Extension);
        //AddHeader(Response, HTTP_HEADER_LAST_MODIFIED, InternalRequestedFileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc.ToString("r"));
        AddHeader(Response, HTTP_HEADER_ENTITY_TAG, string.Concat("\"", InternalRequestedFileEntityTag, "\""));

        if (bIsiPhone)
            AddHeader(Response, HTTP_HEADER_ACCEPT_RANGES, HTTP_HEADER_ACCEPT_RANGES_BYTES);
        else
            AddHeader(Response, HTTP_HEADER_ACCEPT_RANGES, HTTP_HEADER_ACCEPT_RANGES_NONE);
    }
```

Comment: Could you described what you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for you replay.. I have pasted the code what i have implemented. Can you please help me to resolve this. Showing crossed play icon on Iphone Device when i am trying to download.

Comment: how exactly does it fail?

Comment: Not sure.. on iPhone play icon displaying after sometime its broken

Comment: I have deployed the code what is available on the above article but still didn't work. Can you please some one help me on this.